# Qual é o tipo MIME correto?

Tags: javascript, json, mime-type

Para permitir a troca de dados entre o servidor e o navegador, normalmente adoptam-se várias medias, por exemplo quando se pretende retornar um conjunto de dados existendes no banco de dados usando dados do tipo *JSON*.

Existem estes aqui:

- application/json
- application/x-javascript
- text/javascript
- text/x-javascript
- text/x-json

Acontece que não uso nenhuma delas para trabalhar com saídas de dados do tipo *JSON*, normalmente uso `text/plain`, que é para retornos do tipo texto simples.

**Qual é o MIME Type Correto para JSON** ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Em geral todos estes funcionarão mas o mais semântico é o `application/json` conforme [RFC](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt). Usando o correto, fica mais fácil todos consumidores trabalharem corretamente - partindo do princípio que ele esteja seguindo a RFC.

Há situações que ele pode apresentar problemas, por isto não descarte as outras. Cada uma tem um problema com algum navegador ou alguma outra aplicação :)